# What am I missing? Email Verification Not Working in Laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel

I have implemented email verification in my Laravel application manually However, I'm facing an issue where the email verification process does not seem to work as expected. Ideally, I am generating verification URLs with a temporary signed route and sending them to users via email. Upon clicking the verification link, users are directed to a controller action where they verify the email by comparing the parameters in the URL with the user's data in the database.

This is my Verification controller

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class VerificationController extends Controller
{ 
     public function verify(Request $request)
    {
          try {
    // Log or dump the values of route parameters
    logger()->info('ID Parameter:', ['id' => $request->id]);
    logger()->info('Hash Parameter:', ['hash' => $request->hash]);

    // Retrieve the user by ID
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->id);
    logger()->info('Retrieved User:', ['user_id' => $user->id, 'user_email' => $user->email, 'hash' => $user->email_verification_token]);


    // Check if the user has an email verification token
    if ($user->email_verification_token) {
        // Compare the verification token hash from the URL with the stored token
        if ($request->route('id') == $user->getKey() &&
            hash_equals((string) $request->route('hash'), $user->email_verification_token)) {
            // If the verification token matches, mark the email as verified
            $user->email_verified_at = now();
            $user->save();

            // Redirect the user to a success page or display a success message
            return view('verification.verify-success');
        }
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Log the error for debugging
    logger()->error('Verification Error: ' . $e->getMessage());

    // You can handle the error in different ways, such as displaying a generic error message to the user
    return view('verification.verify-error');
}

}
}
```

```
Current Behavior:
```

```
When clicking on the verification link, the page appears to hang indefinitely without any action.
There are no error messages or exceptions displayed, and the page remains blank.
What I've Tried:

I have verified that the verification link contains the correct user ID and hash parameters.
I have checked the database to ensure that the user's email verification token matches the hash parameter in the URL.
I have reviewed the verification logic in my Laravel controller to ensure it is correctly comparing the parameters and marking the email as verified.
```

ideally thee are the logs , the url and the database hash showing the same hash and id
my log info is

ID Parameter: {"id":"7"} Hash Parameter: {"hash":"kR8yO2UdkyehKg1RZHxopxXJAaHYl2GD3u2Yx87fIa3GWrMnYL2TO1JdNGZL"}
Retrieved User: {"user_id":7,"user_email":"cheiayisd@gmail.com","hash":"kR8yO2UdkyehKg1RZHxopxXJAaHYl2GD3u2Yx87fIa3GWrMnYL2TO1JdNGZL"} url :  path/email/verify/7?expires=1707613077&hash=kR8yO2UdkyehKg1RZHxopxXJAaHYl2GD3u2Yx87fIa3GWrMnYL2TO1JdNGZL&signature=bdf584c3619d231aa979e6db8e5abab9bf55a74ab47949f37b41d5c1ebc3c87a

This is my User Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'confirmpassword',
        'role', 
        'email_verification_token'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'confirmpassword',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be guarded from mass assignment.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [
        // Remove 'role' from the $guarded array
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Send the email verification notification.
     */
    public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {
        $this->notify(new \App\Notifications\VerifyEmail);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: One thing that your question is missing is any apparent Java relevance. You've tagged this question as a Java question, but it appears to be all about Laravel and PHP. I've just now tried to fix the question tags for you.

Comment: Did you try to redirect it after verification instead of returning  a view ? ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you get the id from the request in the `verify` function.

```
$user = User::findOrFail($request->id);
```

However, in the link you sent to the user, it appears in the last segment, not as part of the request.

url : path/email/verify/**7**?expires=1707613077&hash=kR.....

Even though I don't know exactly what is written in routes/web.php, it can be fixed if you do it like this.

```
Route::get('path/email/verify/{id}', [VerificationController::class, 'verify']);
```

You should also edit the parameters taken by the Verify function as follows:

```
public function verify(Request $request, int $id)
{
...
}
```

**Optional**

If you wish, you can use model binding in the verify function. So you don't need to use findOrFail.

```
public function verify(Request $request, User $id)
{
...
//$user = User::findOrFail($request->id); You can now remove this line.
...
}
```